# What does this mean: "Head for the fence and try to catch"

Tags: idioms

In a presidential debate, the host tells president Reagan [Reagan's Humor, at the minute 1:21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTIfGFJqLko):

> I like **to head for the fence and try to catch that one** before it goes over, but I'll go on to another question.

and I was wondering if it's a kind of idiom rooted in the Baseball, although I couldn't find what it exactly means searching the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compliment with a hint of disagreement.

If the batter hits a ball over the wall (= the fence), it scores a home run for the team.

The host compares Reagan's answer with a successful hit, very good to argue against (= it's going over the fence), but still one [you can disagree with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nOkd0VweSA&ab_channel=MLB) (=running for the fence and trying to catch it).